# How to read and modify Object passed to a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my main function `App()`, in `useEffect()`, I get data (variable named `document`) using some API with success. My data is the Object with some fields ie `title` and `text`.

I pass this data through my functions and I want different functions to use different parts of the document. Later, I render title with success:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./Title.css"

function Title({document}) {
    return (
        <div className="title">
            {document.title}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Title;
```

I want to render 'text' field too, **BUT** I'd like to split it on newlines

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import React from 'react'

function SourceText({ document }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {document.text.split()}
        </div>
    )
}

export default SourceText
```

Which does not work and returns error

> TypeError: document.text is undefined

which is weird because when I return just `document.text` in divs, this object exists.

I tried to add something like this

```
const [text, setText] = React.useState(null);
React.useEffect(() => {
    setText(document.text)
    console.log(document.text);
}, []);
```

But it does not look like it sets `document.text` value to `text` variable. What I can't get too is that console in the browser prints the entire object after adding these lines of code.

I am new to React and JavaScript and I really don't get how to modify and use the value passed to a function.

Thanks

EDIT:
I pass the document from `App` to `TabGroup`, then to `Source` and then to `SourceText`. The last one is here:

```
import './Source.css';
import SourceText from './SourceText';
import Title from './Title';

function Source({document}) {
  return (
    <div className="source"> 

        <Title title={document.title}/>
        <SourceText document={document} />

    </div>
  );
}

export default Source;
```

As I mentioned Title always renders, and using just `{document.text}` in `SourceText` does work too

Comment: console.log after setText will not work because setText is a async method. It's not updated immediately. Better to show how you fetch document, as well as how you render <SourceText> and <Title>

Comment: Yes I did. When I render just <div>{document.text}</div>, I can see the raw text

Comment: did u use <SourceText document={document} /> or accidentally used <SourceText document={document.text} />? It makes a difference

Comment: This is probably an async issue. Make sure to not render `<SourceText document={document} />` if the `document` is not yet loaded, or use a default value which is able to be handled by the render.

Comment: Please share your code of passing props to the child component.

Comment: Adding an effect or extra state to the component will not help. The error message means that you're passing an object without a `.text` property as the `document`.

Comment: @Bergi I am sure document has text, at least in return, because I can see it when I return just it. when I want to use useEffect and add extra variable text, it seems this variable is empty, I renders nothing.

Comment: @DavidS1992 "*I am sure document has text*" - well the `TypeError` disagrees there :-) You haven't shown your `App` yet where the object is constructed, but it seems at least part of the time it does not have that property (maybe it's loaded asynchronously?). When rendering an `undefined` value in react, it will be ignored and nothing will show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.text.split()` will return an array. [str.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) without any parameters returns an array.

You cannot render arrays directly unless you loop through each item. Also, always add checks for null | undefined when trying to render values.

`{document?.text && document.text.split().map...}`

Comment: You're right. `            {document.text && document.text.split('\n').map((line) => (line))}
` let split work.

Answer (score 0):

After @Tom Bombadil post I was able to find the solution

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import React from 'react'


function SourceText({ document }) {

    return (
        <div>
            {document.text && document.text.split('at').map((line) => (line))}

        </div>
    )
}

export default SourceText
```

EDIT: didn't take too long to realize my earlier notes were wrong. Seems like it was indeed some async issue - hard to understand for me because the error and result depend on the duration of data fetching.

Comment: No, you should absolutely not use state and effects for this.

Comment: @Bergi You're right, thanks. So it is not a problem to perform some calculations in return()? By calculations I mean checking to what group of annotations each word belongs to and then coloring words according to groups.